# Stripe one time payment plan

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I created a stripe subscription plan for one day and my customer automatically charged each day but I don't want to charge and subscribe that plan again automatically.I want to end subscription after one day(when plan period ends).
Is there any way or parameter on subscription creation time to tell the stripe that don't charge customer again when plan period ends?

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you only charging the customer once? In that case, why use a subscription at all? Why not just do a once-off charge?

Comment: can I remove subscription when the subscription period ends?

Comment: Sure, but my point is that that would only result in the customer being charged once, so why use a subscription? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: As I'm always checking that is user has subscription so that user can access the paid features.